# Quartz.NET Runtime Scheduler will only get db connection string from app.config

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net

I've created an asp.net core web app with Quartz for my job scheduling. I'm writing the job blueprints into a db at startup and then adding triggers and scheduling the job once I have all the info I need(user input).

Yesterday I had this issue, that Quartz couldn't find the job in the jobstore when I tried to schedule it. Eventually I figured out that it was looking in the RAM jobstore for some reason.

I tried a number of different things, did some googling to make sure I had everything setup correctly and in the end, on a whim, I figured I'd try adding the connection strings in an app.config. Suddenly quartz happily fetched the connection strings and scheduled my jobs. I added the app.config because I initially used the app.config for my connection strings when setting up the project before figuring out that using the appsettings.json is the preferred method for a .net core project. So maybe there is some setting somewhere that still prompts quartz to look for an app.config? I just have no clue where that could be.

Also, as I said, when setting up the jobs in my program.cs it gets the strings from appsettings.json just as it is supposed to.

program.cs with a most .AddJob omitted for brevity.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
    
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    var jobKey = new JobKey("HR First Contact", "DEFAULT");
    q.AddJob<MailHRNewEmployee>(jobKey, j => j
        .StoreDurably()
        .WithDescription("job blueprint"));

    q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        // s.PerformSchemaValidation = true;
        s.UseProperties = true;
        s.RetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        s.UseMySqlConnector(MySql =>
        {
            MySql.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString");
            MySql.TablePrefix = "QRTZ_";
        });
        s.UseJsonSerializer();
    });
});
    
builder.Services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Quartz"));
builder.Services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Scheduling.IgnoreDuplicates = true;
    options.Scheduling.OverWriteExistingData = true;
});

builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
{
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

my Scheduler - most of it omitted for brevity, I can add the rest but it's just fetching data I need for the jobmap.

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            this.scheduler = await schedFact.GetScheduler();
            ITrigger jtriggz = CreateTriggerFirstContact();
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jtriggz, cancellationToken);
            await scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
        }

private ITrigger CreateTriggerFirstContact()
        {
            return Quartz.TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity(_employee.FName + _employee.LName, "HR Contact").UsingJobData("FName", _employee.FName).UsingJobData("LName", _employee.LName).UsingJobData("Gender", _employee.Gender).UsingJobData("Id", Convert.ToString(_employee.Id)).UsingJobData("Empfaenger", recipient).UsingJobData("EmpfaengerName", HRManager.Name).UsingJobData("EmpfaengerGeschlecht", HRManager.Gender).StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)).ForJob("HR First Contact").Build();
        }
```

## **Edit**

Forgot to add this, but I managed to resolve the issue.

The problem was that I am initializing Quartz in my program.cs using Mircosoft Dependency Injection but I'm not properly utilizing it in my scheduler.

Instead of the following lines in my StartAsync Method:

```
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        this.scheduler = await schedFact.GetScheduler();
```

I need to take the object I am creating in my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
{
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

and pass it to the scheduler, like this:

```
public RunningScheduler(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
{
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
} 
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        this.scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
}
```

This was a fundamental misunderstanding of DI on my part and after reeducating myself on DI I figured it out pretty quickly.